# Como configurar botões com HTML e CSS?

Tags: html5, css3

Conforme imagem estou tentando deixar os botões um ao lado do outro, de forma que fique responsivo e não desconfigure, como está na imagem, o botão 1 está maior e atrás dos botões 2 e 3. Estou há 3 dias tentando de tudo, inline-block, float, e nada dá certo. Por favor preciso de um help urgentemente. Não sei o que estou fazendo de errado.

[Botoes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCXOu.png)

HTML

```
            <div class="manual mx-auto">
                <div style="margin: 10px;" " class="title-manual justify-content-center d-flex align-items-center w-100 manual-um">
                        <a href="https://manualdofoliao2020.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/" target="_blank">Botao1</a>

           <div class="manual mx-auto"> 
                </div>
                <div style="margin: 10px;" class="title-manual justify-content-center d-flex align-items-center w-100">
                    <a href="https://manualdofoliao2020.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/" target="_blank">Botao2</a>
                    
            </div>
                
            <div class="title-manual justify-content-center d-flex align-items-center w-100">
                <a href="https://manualdofoliao2020.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/" target="_blank">Botao3 </a>
        
        </div>
                
            </div>

            <!--FIM -->`][1]
```

css

```
 }
.title-manual{
    font-family: 'CooperHewitt-Bold';
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #000, -1px -1px 0px #000, 0px 2px 0px #000, 2px 0px 0px #000, -2px 0px 0px #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    font-size: 28px;
    z-index: 2;
    position:relative;
    background:#7726FF url("../img/manual-bg.jpg") repeat center center / cover;
    height: 55px;
    border:2px solid #000;
}
.title-manual a,.title-manual a:visited,.title-manual a:hover{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Você pode utilizar flex-box dentro do container dos botões, segue um exemplo onde implementei um layout parecido com a imagem de referencia, removi apenas as classes do seu código para facilitar seu entendimento da solução adotada

HTML:

```
<div class="container-buttons">
<div class="btn">
  <a href="https://manualdofoliao2020.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/" target="_blank">Botao1</a>
</div>
<div class="btn">
  <a href="https://manualdofoliao2020.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/" target="_blank">Botao2</a>
</div>
<div class="btn">
  <a href="https://manualdofoliao2020.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/" target="_blank">Botao3 </a>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
.container-buttons {
font-family: 'CooperHewitt-Bold';
color: #fff;
text-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #000, -1px -1px 0px #000, 0px 2px 0px #000, 2px 0px 0px #000, -2px 0px 0px #000;
border-radius: 10px;
font-size: 28px;
background: #7726FF url("../img/manual-bg.jpg") repeat center center / cover;
border: 2px solid #000;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
}

.btn {
border: 2px solid black;
padding: 7px 36px;
border-radius: 10px;
}

.btn a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
border-color: transparent;
}
</style>
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Obrigada Douglas, fiz de outra maneira e deu certo!! É minha primeira pergunta e já teve -4 curtidas. Ao invés de enviarem um comentário ou qualquer outra coisa para poder entender como funciona, preferem fazer algo do gênero, preferem reagir negativamente.  É uma pena algo do tipo. Mas há pessoas que como você tentam ajudar de alguma forma. Mais uma vez obrigada!